# Script to force message "Java Update Needed"

Tags: powershell, installation

I am using a owt installer for application which uses a specific version of Java. When I run the installer the Internet Explorer open and give me this message:

[image]

Because of automation install, I am trying to do a PowerShell script to force this message and choose the choice:

> Later - Continue and you will be reminded to update again later

I know that there is possibility to do it with the methods `SendKeys` and `Sleep` but I do not know if it is good choice.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but. 1) stop the windows process called `jusched`. 2) delete the registry entry called `SunJavaUpdateSched` in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. 3) install your application. 4) recreate the registry entry `SunJavaUpdateSched` (so make a note of the value first..)

Comment: I tried apply your suggestion like this: `Stop-Process -processname jusched -force` and `Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\" -name "SunJavaUpdateSched"`. But it did not work...